# get the failed step name from KIKUSUI TOS9200/TOS9201

Tags: hipot, scpi

I'm using the KIKUSUI TOS9200/TOS9201 HIPOT tester, by setting a program number.
If a step in the program fails, I use the MON command get the step monitor values.
The information I need is in the step NAME. How can I get the failed step name?